# UIActivityViewController issue

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uikit

I am trying to add a sharing functionality to my app. I have created a button and imported the UIKIT framework. Xcode keeps on throwing the error **no visible @interface for 'MainMenuScene' declares selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion**. Any idea how to solve this problem?

---

My code mainmenuscene.m

```
- (void)share {
    NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some initial text."], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    NSArray * excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeMessage];

    UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];     
}
```

---

MainMenuScene.h

```
#import "CCNode.h"
#import <UIKit/UIActivityViewController.h>


@interface MainMenuScene : CCNode{

UIViewController *viewController;
UIActivityViewController *activityController;


}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `self` in this case is calling the `MainMenuScene` object. Your 'MainMenuScene' is of type CCNode which is of type NSObject. You need to call the

```
presentViewController:animated:completion
```

on an object that inherits from UIViewController. Specifically, you need to call it from your view controller that you want to present your activityController from.

Answer (score 0):

To use method:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

Target class must be a subclass of `UIViewController`. Here your MainMenuScene is subclass of CCNode that isn't inherited from `UIViewController` even indirectly.

So please find an appropriate view controller (it may be your root controller) and present `UIActivityViewController` on it